# AJAX call creates new session in Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, session

I have a Symfony application. I am saving some information on the session in it, using `request->getSession()->set(key, value)`.

If I call an action via a client side AJAX call, I can't access the session variables, which I saved earlier. It looks like the AJAX call generates me a completely new session (new session id, compared to the one present in the main flow).

I have the following settings in `config.yml`:

```
session:         
    cookie_lifetime:         3600
    cookie_httponly:         false
```

The strange thing is, that on localhost I get the same sessionId via AJAX (so on localhost everything works fine). The issue started to appear after I deployed it on a webserver.

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you call an action from the controller via Ajax? In which you mean a server-side Ajax call? That's a bit weird. Let's say you would do that, the server does not have the same session but it will create a new session that is not related to the user its session.

Think you should use the Controller its `forward` method. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller

Or move the method you'd like to call to it's own class and configure a service for that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/configurators.html

Comment: Sorry, if my description wasn't clear enough. What I meant was that I am simply using a client side AJAX call to call a method from the Symfony application. E.g.
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'cart/add/'+id
    });

Comment: This should work, we do it all the time. Probably your session cookie is `httponly`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-httponly